# Catch all requested paths in Springboot RestController

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am looking for a way to get an Endpoint in Springboot that catches all requests send to `/`. Ideally everything behind `/` should be handed in as a String parameter.

An example request could look like this: `http://myproxy.com/foo/bar?blah=blubb`
I tried a RestController for `/`

```
@RestController
public class ProxyRestController {

    @RequestMapping("/{restOfPath}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleGetRequests(@PathVarialbe("restOfPath") String path) {
        return ResponseEntity.of(Optional.of(""));
    }

}
```

The endpoint doesn't catch the example because it would be routed to `/foo/bar` whereas `/foo` is caught.

How would I achieve a "catch all" endpoint in SpringBoot? It could also be in another way than a `@RestController` I just need to be inside a component and send a http response back to the caller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adapt this code to match yours:

```
@Controller
public class RestController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/**/{path:.*}")
public String index(final HttpServletRequest request) {
    final String url = request.getRequestURI();

    return "something";
}
}
```

Comment: You have also the ability to handle some specific url inside your function by using this code:

```if (url.startsWith("/something")) {
        return "something";
    }```

Comment: Basically the rule is to add a regex as a value of ```value``` parameter of ```@RequestMapping``` annotation

Comment: I tried adding your regex to the mapping but I still get a 404 when I run my example request

Comment: It works when I use `"/**/{path:.*}"` though, maybe you can correct the answer so I can accept it.